# .htaccess rewrite redirecting to folders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory

I am trying to remove the .php extensions from my webpage but am running into trouble. Currently, I have this in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^((.*/)*[^./]+)/*$ $1.php [L]
```

For the most part, this works. However, my site is structured so that there are folders and pages with the same name, such as example.com/page1.php

But there is also a folder `page1` so that example.com/page1/subpage.php shows up like I want.

This .htaccess code correctly directs example.com/page1/subpage to the .php file, but for example.com/page1, it tries to redirect to the folder instead of page1.php, so I get an error that access is forbidden.

How can I fix this with rewrites, or should I organize/structure my files differently?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your 2 rules with this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: I ended up changing it so that instead of page1.php, it was page1/index.php and that solved my problem and make my organization cleaner as well. Thanks, though!

Comment: Glad to know your problem got solved but not many are in position to change their file names. I will leave my answer for those folks here